# ionic5 issue Click is not working inside ion-recoder list

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

item click handlers don't fire when tapping on reorder items. and ion-reorder-group is set to disabled false

````
<ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="onRenderItems($event)" disabled="false">
    <ion-reorder>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          Item 7
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-reorder>
  
    <ion-reorder (click)="itemClick()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          Item 8
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-reorder>
  </ion-reorder-group>```
````

Comment: I have the same error. It only works for me if I set `disabled="true"`. It seems like the `ion-reorder-group` stops propagation to do the reordering.